# Send email using data from pivot table

Tags: laravel, email

I want to ask for help regarding my project. I want to send emails to all users that have a certain group_id.

This is my [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWSrL.png)

For example, I want to send an email to all users who have group_id = 1, so how do I want to call the email column in the User table with the respective condition?

```
$group = Group::find($req->groupID);

Mail::send('newmeetingEmail', array(
    'groupName' => $req->groupName,
    'meetingDate' => $req->meetingDate,
    'meetingTime' => $req->meetingTime,
    'meetingDesc' => $req->meetingDesc,
    'meetingLink' => $req->meetingLink,
    'meetingModerator' => $req->meetingModerator,
), function ($message) use ($group) {
    $message->from('abc@gmail.com');
    $message->to($group->creator->email)->subject('Class session');
});
```

Comment: You can't use `DB::table()` and Relationships; `$group->creator->email` will not work here. Do you have Models and Relationships setup for `Group` and `User`? If you do, you can do `Group::find($req->groupID)`, then loop over `$group->users` and Email them accordingly.

Comment: yes i have the model and relationship for them

Comment: Then use them; using the `DB` facade should only be done when you can't accomplish it via Models. If you get stuck again, you can edit your question with more details.

Comment: i have edit my code but when i run it shows error (Property [email] does not exist on this collection instance.) what should i do? Actually i dont understand (then loop over $group->users and Email them accordingly.) part well.

Comment: `$group` is a single `Group` instance. `$group->creator` returns a Collection of multiple `User` instances, so you can't access `->email`, as that is a Property of a single `User`, not a Collection of multiple Users. That is what I mean by you need to loop: `foreach($group->creator as $creator)`, then you can access `$creator->email`. Also, `creator` is a bad relationship name, since it is Singular, but returns multiple rows. `creators` would be better.

Comment: i already changed the relationship name and yeah i follow your step and its works! Thank you so much for helping me, really appreaciated it.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! You just have to be aware of when you're dealing with a Single Instance vs a Collection of Multiple Instances of a Model; if you try to access a Property, like `->email`, it won't work for a Collection, as the code won't know which `email` you're trying to reference. Cheers! 